# Restrict Intellij IDEA backward analysis

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to analyze one Maven module of a Java project in Intellij IDEA using the Analyze->Inspect Code menu item. I have restricted the scope of the analysis to that project. When it runs the analysis, it gets to a phase called "Perform Backward Analysis" where it is looking at files outside of the module I ran the analysis on. Specifically, it is running the analysis on a large number of XML and HTML files that are used as part of the help documentation of the project and are not related to the code.

At the rate it is going, it is probably not going to finish the analysis this decade, so how do I either get Intellij to really only look at the files in the current directory, or turn off backward analysis, or exclude the XML/HTML files from the backward analysis so that it eventually finished?

Answer (score 0):

When you go to Analyze->Inspect Code, the dialog gives you the option to limit to the "Current file" or the module that is active in the editor when you invoked it. You can also define a custom scope such as just java files or files in a particular package.. Click on the button with the ellipsis. In the dialog, click the help button for the syntax for defining scopes.

[image]

Comment: I'm restricting the scope to the Module I want to analyze (the first setting you have circled above), but when the analysis gets to the "Perform Backward Analysis" phase, it is still looking at files from the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom scope to do this. If you have a look at the custom scope dialog you'll find an option to exclude selected paths, or you can simply type a pattern, such as `!*..*.xml`.

Comment: I created a custom scope and added the pattern "[my-module]:*..*&&![help-module]:*..*&&!*..*.xml", where my-module is the module I want to analyze and help-module is the module with the XML files that are taking forever to analyze. I would expect the files to be ignored both by module and by file type, but it is still analyzing the XML files in help-module when it gets to "Perform Backward Analysis"

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit return and had to go back and edit to finish the comment.

Comment: Looks like you're SOL then. Sorry. Perhaps you could register this as a potential bug on the intellij bug tracker?